# Speed up processing time while creating smaller files from a larger one

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, file, loops

I have a little script that will run through a wordlist of around 300,000 words and create files that are exactly 999KB from that file. This works perfectly and all but it's extremely slow due to me opening the file every iteration, how can I fix this script to where it will have the exact same behavior but will speed up the processing time?

```
import os
import hashlib


data = []
count = 1


with open("dicts/included_dicts/dictionaries/000webhost.txt") as a:
    for line in a.readlines():
        h = hashlib.md5()
        h.update(line.strip())
        data.append(h.hexdigest() + ": " + line.strip() + "\n")

for item in data:
    with open("dicts/included_dicts/rainbowtables/md5_{}.rtc".format(count), "a+") as b:
        if os.stat("dicts/included_dicts/rainbowtables/md5_{}.rtc".format(count)).st_size <= 1022162L:
            b.write(item)
        else:
            count += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing the variable outside the loop:

```
b = open("dicts/included_dicts/rainbowtables/md5_{}.rtc".format(count), "a+")
for item in data:
    if os.stat("dicts/included_dicts/rainbowtables/md5_{}.rtc".format(count)).st_size <= 1022162L:
        b.write(item)
    else:
        count += 1
        b.close()
        b = open("dicts/included_dicts/rainbowtables/md5_{}.rtc".format(count), "a+")
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't produce the same behaviour, the files size is 1003KB instead of 999KB

Comment: @papasmurf Try decreasing the size comparison value.

Answer (score 1):

Just make the string and write it.

Another way to go, guess this answer might depend upon platform, don't know about empty file sizes on other systems then linux.

```
cache = ""
count = 1
for item in data:
    cache += item+"\n"
    if sys.getsizeof(cache+item+"\n") > 999999-4:
        with open("dicts/included_dicts/rainbowtables/md5_{}.rtc".format(count), "w") as b:
            b.write(cache)
        count += 1
        cache = item
```